# SwiftUI: How do I loop through an array of Int inside "For Each"

Tags: arrays, swift, loops, swiftui, swift5

I am getting the following error "Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with function builder 'ViewBuilder'" 
Not able to find similar troubleshoot anywhere.

```swift
struct FavoriteView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData
    @State var isfavorite = false
    var favoriteindex = [1,2,3]

    var body: some View {
       NavigationView {
          List {
             ForEach(userData.labvaluesUserdata) {section in
                for numbers in favoriteindex {
                   if section.id == (numbers) {
                      ItemRow(list: section)
                   }
                }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

With this I am able to get the first index. Any simple way to loop through ?

```swift
List {
   ForEach(userData.labvaluesUserdata) { section in
      if section.id == self.favoriteindex.first {
         ItemRow(list: section)
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you see this: https://jasonzurita.com/swiftui-if-statement/ - it has exactly that error and a potential workaround.

Comment: Might have something to do with 7 LEFT braces, and only 5 Right braces ?

Comment: Yeah had seen that. But that is for a Bool value. For me, I need to loop over each integer in the array "favoriteindex" @koen

Comment: @donPablo thanks for pointing out that. But that was due to error in pasting the code here as I had to reduce some navigation bar code. I have edited the code now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it, and it's simple as that

```
enum SectionType: Identifiable {
    var id: Int {
        switch self {
        case .first:
            return 1
        case .second:
            return 2
        case .third:
            return 3
        }
    }

    case first
    case second
    case third
}

struct UserData {
    var labvaluesUserdata: [SectionType] = [.first, .second, .third, .first, .second]
}

struct ItemRow: View {
    var list: SectionType

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(list.id)")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var userData = UserData()
    @State var favoriteindex: [Int] = [2, 3]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(userData.labvaluesUserdata) {section in
                    if self.favoriteindex.contains(where: { $0 == section.id }) {
                        ItemRow(list: section)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Updated: added brand new solution. Tried it and it works**

Comment: What is SectionType here ? I am getting this error "Use of undeclared type 'SectionType' "

Comment: oh, man It's type of your section in labvaluesUserdata array. So just replace it with your values type of labvaluesUserdata array.

Comment: Nope!!! labvaluesUserdata is an array of Struct. I get this error ii I use "MTLStruct Type" ...Cannot invoke initializer for type 'ForEach<_, _, _>' with an argument list of type '([Labvalueslist], @escaping (MTLStructType) -> some View)'

Comment: I was able to go further but held up here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59268923/swift-ui-missing-return-in-a-function-expected-to-return-some-view

Comment: @Dar I've updated my answer. Check it. Also it solves https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59268923/swift-ui-missing-return-in-a-function-expected-to-return-some-view So you can close it if it's possible.